# jQuery Searchbox IE9 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, focus

I'm working on an issue here that only occurs in IE8/9

We have 2 search boxes. One in the header that uses jQuery's Autocomplete, and the other which is specifically for an archiving feature we have on certain pages.  What should happen is if the Autocomplete searchbox is in focus and we hit Enter after typing something in, it searches with that value.  Easy enough.

However, in IE8/9, no matter which text box has focus, the Enter key will trigger that event.

Here's what we've got:

```
jQuery(".autocomplete").keydown(function(event) {
    if (jQuery(".autocomplete").is(":focus")){
        var query;
        if (event.which === 13) {
          event.preventDefault();
          query = this.value;
          return window.location.href = "/search?q=" + query;
        }
    }
});
```

I've also tried .keypress() and it yields the same result.   We're using jQuery 2.0.0

Our team is relatively new to jQuery, so we're probably just doing this wrong.

It should only be firing on searchboxes with the .autocomplete class, and only if that particular box has focus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, apparently a different team had added a .js file that was interfering with the operation of this jquery script in our file.